# how to use threading and sockets in c correctly?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking

I created a simple chat app with threading and sockets, however my conn_1 can only send messages and conn_2 only receives messages. But they should do receiving and sending. I tried that the programm runs the two functions in the background, which are receiving and sending the messages to the other connection. Can some one help me? I dont know what I did wrong.

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT_CONN1 4444
#define PORT_CONN2 4445

char buf1[1024];
char buf2[1024];

int msg_1() {
  while(1) {
    recv(conn_1, &buf1, 1024, 0);
    send(conn_2, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
  }
}

int msg_2() {
  while(1) {
    recv(conn_2, &buf2, 1024, 0);
    send(conn_1, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
  }
}

int main() {
  int sockfd_1, sockfd_2, conn_1, conn_2;
  struct sockaddr_in host_addr, client_addr;
  socklen_t sin_size;
  int recv_length=1, ok=1;

  sockfd_1 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  sockfd_2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  setsockopt(sockfd_1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &ok, sizeof(int));
  setsockopt(sockfd_2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &ok, sizeof(int));

  host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  host_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_CONN1);
  host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
  memset(&(host_addr.sin_zero), "\0", 8);

  bind(sockfd_1, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

  host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  host_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_CONN2);
  host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
  memset(&(host_addr.sin_zero), "\0", 8);

  bind(sockfd_2, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

  listen(sockfd_1, 5);
  listen(sockfd_2, 5);

  while(1) {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    conn_1 = accept(sockfd_1, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);
    conn_2 = accept(sockfd_2, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, msg_1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, msg_2, NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    close(conn_1);
    close(conn_2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I put an answer to help you to write your program but without giving a solution, you will learn much more doing it by yourself. Of course edit your question with a new version then do not hesitate to ask for help if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know what I did wrong.

Some hints.

First your program cannot compile

- in `msg_1` and `msg_2` you use the `conn_1` and `conn_2` which are undefined (they are *local* variables in `main`)
- the second argument of `memset` must be an *int* specifying the byte used to set the block of memory, you give an array of *char* (`"\0"`)
- the signature of `msg_1` and `msg_2` are not compatible with `thread_create`

You want to exchange data between two threads through socket(s), you do not need to use two *sockets* for that, only one is enough because a *socket* is bi directional (contrarily with the *pipes*).

To have a *socket* you need a server and a client, the same *thread* cannot be both of them, `accept` blocks the *thread* until a client connects. In your program the main *thread* class *accept* but there is no client to connect, so you are definitively blocked.

The fact the end of `main` is in a `while` is quite obscure. This is also the case of `pthread_exit(NULL);` if you use that functions this is in the two *threads* but not in `main`.

Note the used socket is a *stream*, that means when you read on it you cannot suppose something about the number of bytes you get. This is the difference with the *datagram*.

So someone needs to be the server of your socket and someone *else* running in parallel must the a client. Because the *socket* will be used to exchange data between *threads* it seems natural one is the server and the other one the client. Note to use two additional *threads* is useless because your *main* *thread* will have nothing to do, so you can just have one additional *thread* rather than two.

To simplify I encourage you to do a first version where the *main* is the server and the only one additional *thread* is the client. Warning to not launch the additional *thread* too early nor too late, that means after the `listen` but before the `accept`.